# Finding the limit of the area of a Koch Snowflake

Tags: limits, fractals

this is my first question for this site and I made this account specifically for help with the following topic.
I am doing a research presentation on the Koch Snowflake, specifically, the area. 
So far, I have been attempting to generalize a formula for finding the area of the snowflake at *n* iterations, and I am now trying to find the limit as *n* tends toward infinity.

So, basically, what is the limit for the following?:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=2}^{n} \frac{3 \cdot 4^{r-2}}{9^{r-1}}  \cdot \frac{s^2 \sqrt{3}}{4} $$

Comment: is your formula right?

Comment: Hint. Can you find a geometric series in your expression?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=2}^{n} \frac{3 \cdot 4^{r-2}}{9^{r-1}}  \cdot \frac{s^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}=\frac{s^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}\cdot \frac 13\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(\frac 49\right)^k$$
Where $k=r-2$.  Now you have a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) to sum.

Comment: I see how you put the \frac{3\cdot\sqrt{3}}{4} on the left side of the limit, but would you mind explaining where the \frac{1}{3} came from?

edit: I guess there is no LaTeX in comments, I apologize.

Comment: There was a $3$ in the numerator and one more $9$ than $4$ in the powers, so I pulled out $\frac 39$  You get MathJax in comments by using dollar signs, but it doesn't render as you are typing.  I just do the best I can, then check how it renders after I post it and fix any problems.  If you want to "sandbox" it, you can type the question as a new answer, verify that it renders as you want, then copy/paste into a comment box.

Answer (score 0):

The following forms a GP with $a=\frac{1}{9}$ and $r=\frac{4}{9}$.
$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=2}^{n} \frac{3 \cdot 4^{r-2}}{9^{r-1}}  \cdot \frac{s^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}\\
=\ &\frac{ 3\sqrt{3}\cdot s^2}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=2}^{n} \frac{ 4^{r-2}}{9^{r-1}} \\
=\ &\frac{ 3\sqrt{3}\cdot s^2}{4}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{4}{9}}\\
=\ &\frac{ 3\sqrt{3}\cdot s^2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\\
=\ &\frac{ 3\sqrt{3}\cdot s^2}{20}
\end{align}\\
$$

Comment: How can you tell that the formula is wrong?

Comment: The final expression should have been $\frac{2\sqrt3}{5}\cdot s^2$. If you need reference, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake#Area_of_the_Koch_snowflake) out.